# Change URL of my php site using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, url, url-rewriting

i want to changes url

from `domain/blog.php?blog_id_=30&&slug_name=asdsad`

to `domain/blog/asdsad`

using .htaccess file plase help me

Answer (score 1):

`blog_id_=30&&slug_name=asdsad` can just be `blog_id_=30&slug_name=asdsad`, no need of double `&`.

- Match the query string as is with the `slug_name` using regex on `QUERY_STRING`.
- Rewrite matched URI `blog.php` to the matched regex value in query string for `slug_name`.
- Add `R = 302` for testing purposes and make it `R = 301` on live server for permanent redirection if you wish to do so.

**Snippet:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} slug_name=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?blog.php$ /blog/%1 [NC,L,QSD,R=302]
```

**Demo:** https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=fecc97ef-2b2e-4ee2-87dd-26138e7b4bfd

Comment: @SabirHala What is your localhost URL?

Comment: Although I suspect the OP is asking for a lot more than simply redirecting from old to new  here. They appear to want to actually _change_ the URL on their site using (only) `.htaccess` - which is not realistic.